# Conditional association with nested form field doesn't validate properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms, has-many, belongs-to

**Rails 6.0.0.beta3
Ruby  2.6.1**

I have two model associations between `Item` and  `Variant` as below:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
...
  has_many :variants
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :variants,
                                reject_if: :all_blank,
                                allow_destroy: true

end
```

and Variant model as below:

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, -> { where(kind: :article) }
end
```

As above, we have a conditional relation for `belongs_to` which depends on `Item` field `kind` to have value `article`.

**Problem**:
While creating an `item` which has nested form fields for `variant` it raises the validation as expected for `kind: :article` but it raises for all other values of `kind` like `kind: :novel`. 
On rails console, I tried to manually create

```
item = Item.create(kind: :article)
item.variants.create

...

item = Item.create(kind: :novel)
item.variants.create
it raises validation error 'should be of kind: :article only'
```

**it works on console but not with nested form fields.**
Other related known issue case: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25198

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a validation of the item kind in the `Variant` model instead of a `where` in the `belongs_to`.

because in your case `Item.create!(kind: :novel).variants.create!` is raising an error (`Item must exist` when I tried it).

btw got interested and made a minimal test repo (https://github.com/localhostdotdev/bug/tree/belongs-to-where-and-accepts-nested-attributes) (doesn't have the form though).